# OpenGL mipmapping: level outside the range?

Tags: opengl, textures, mipmaps

I'm going deeper on OpenGL texture mipmapping.

I noticed in the specification that mipmap levels less than *zero* and greater than *log2(maxSize) + 1* are allowed.

Effectively *TexImage2D* doesn't specify errors for level parameter. So... Probably those mipmaps are not accessed automatically using the standard texture access routines...

How could be effectively used this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the negative case, the [glTexImage2D's man page](http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml) says:

```
GL_INVALID_VALUE is generated if level is less than 0.
```

For the `greater than log2(maxsize)` case, [the specification](http://www.opengl.org/documentation/specs/version2.0/glspec20.pdf) says what happens to those levels in `Raterization/Texturing/Texture Completeness`. The short of it is that, yes, they are ignored.